# Install specific version of R to the Docker Image

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

I'm able to install R in a docker image using:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
    ca-certificates software-properties-common gnupg2 gnupg1 \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 \
    && add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'

RUN apt-get -y install r-base r-base-dev
```

The problem with the command above is that it takes the latest released version of R. I want to stick to a specific version, e.g. R 4.3.2 and don't be effected by future releases. How can I have docker image based on R 4.3.2?

Comment: You'll most likely want to install from source. Have a look at the [rocker](https://rocker-project.org/images/versioned/r-ver.html) images, in particular their [R install script](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/scripts/install_R_source.sh).

Comment: Using base image other than FROM ubuntu:20.04 might create some problems for me. The second link might help tho but I was more interested in doing the changes in the DockerFile itself.

Comment: They have (archived) images per version [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/tree/master/r-ver), but moved to a shell script to handle the install because it's not exactly the same for R 3.6 and >=4.0. It should be really straightforward to do what you want from these files.